# Recover Error in downloaded file using wget

Tags: wget

I downloaded ubuntu-full dvd of 11.10 about 1.5 GB using wget command in ubuntu 9.4.

Unfortunately file downloaded completely, but when I burn to dvd it doesn't start.MD5sum was incorrect.

I checked disk with error checking tool. One error found in splash file.i think now how can I recover image file, so my download doesn't waste. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying md5 error was on the iso file itself or the files on the dvd you burnt?  Check the iso hash first

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download a new DVD, I do not think you can recover with wget.

This is a great user case for using torrents ;) The torrent client will download the file in chunks which are then checksummed. If a single chunk is invalid, only that part has to be downloaded again instead of the whole file in case of a regular HTTP download.

FYI the DVD does not contain additional packages, it just contains additional language support, so unless you need the language support, the CD should be sufficient.

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/24376

Answer (score 0):

I think you have several options here.  One would be to disable md5sum in brasero by going to the edit plugins menu and disabling checksum on files and disks.  I do this usually as a matter of course on the disk just because it takes FOREVER to check the disks and I don't usually find it necessary.  A single splash file being messed up may not effect your ability to use the disk at all.  Another, if you have a reliable internet connection would be to just download the Ubuntu CD and download other packages as needed.  The benefit to this is that you get the most up to date packages from the repositories instead of getting them from the DVD.  Another option would be to replace the file in the iso. Instructions for doing so can be found here:  http://www.ehow.com/how_7469146_modify-iso-image-linux.html